# Filter List of a model using linq

Tags: c#, linq

I have a Model with List inside it, is there any way to filter that list?

What I'm trying is:

```
List<Booking> a = await _context.Set<Booking>().Include(u => u.BookingLine).Include(u => u.BookingStatus).ToListAsync();
```

Inside that Booking model, there is a List. I just want to get all the StatusId = 1 inside that BookingStatus.

Booking model and BookingStatus model has the same BookingId. I don't know where do I put the Where() inside that linq.

I tried like this but it returned an error:

```
_context.Set<Booking>().Include(u => u.BookingLine).Include(u => u.BookingStatus
                        .LastOrDefault(a => a.StatusId == 1 || a.StatusId == 7 || a.StatusId == 13)).ToListAsync();
```

Error:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: The expression 'u.BookingStatus.AsQueryable().LastOrDefault(a => (((a.StatusId == 1) OrElse (a.StatusId == 7)) OrElse (a.StatusId == 13)))' is invalid inside an 'Include' operation, since it does not represent a property access: 't => t.MyProperty'. To target navigations declared on derived types, use casting ('t => ((Derived)t).MyProperty') or the 'as' operator ('t => (t as Derived).MyProperty'). Collection navigation access can be filtered by composing Where, OrderBy(Descending), ThenBy(Descending), Skip or Take operations. For more information on including related data
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you meant to use "Where" instead of "LastOrDefault".

something like:

```
_context.Set<Booking>().Include(u => u.BookingLine).Include(u => u.BookingStatus
                    .Where(a => a.StatusId == 1 || a.StatusId == 7 || a.StatusId == 13)).ToListAsync();
```

Microsoft example of [Eager Loading](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data/eager):

```
using (var context = new BloggingContext())
{
    var filteredBlogs = context.Blogs
        .Include(
            blog => blog.Posts
               .Where(post => post.BlogId == 1)
               .OrderByDescending(post => post.Title)
               .Take(5))
        .ToList();
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I ended up like this:  `return await _context.Set<Booking>()
                    .Include(u => u.BookingLine)                    
                    .Include(u => u.BookingStatus.Where(p => p.StatusId == 1 || p.StatusId == 13 || p.StatusId == 7))
                    .Where(a => a.BookingStatus.Any(p => p.StatusId == 1 || p.StatusId == 13 || p.StatusId == 7))
                    .ToListAsync();  ` which is similar on your answer. Is there anything that I can modify on my code?

Comment: You don't need the second "Where", because you are retrieving a filtered set already, and filtering it again won't do anything. try the code in the answer and comment again if something went wrong.
Otherwise please accept the answer if it helped you.